# Which opensource java or .net project has best unit test coverage?

Tags: java, .net, unit-testing

I want to dive more into the unit testing concepts. An open source project which will illustrate the best practices in unit testing is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work on [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) (original Java version) and I think it is worth considering as a source of study for a few reasons:

1. Lots of unit tests. Certainly not the highest coverage but there are plenty to look at.
2. Diverse technology. There are pojos, tag libs, velocity macros, spring, etc.
3. Uneven quality of unit tests. Because we take contributions from outside the quality and throughness of unit tests vary. The core classes are very well tested. Lots of the contributions are untested or poorly tested. Consider the poorly tested ones as "an exercise left for the reader".  ;)
4. Maybe the best reason: You can ask questions about the tests on [developer mailing list](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/developers.html). In the best case you could even end up writing tests for some of the untested areas and get coaching on your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org) (.NET unit testing software) would be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get hold of the [Spring Framework](http://springframework.org/) source code, the team behind it advocates test driven development and the framework is available for both Java .net.